How to add CORS allow-origin-control-access header to Gateway preflight error responses in NEST?
I have an file upload architecture at my company where we use gateway(preflight) -> lambda(request) -> s3. aws gateway has a 10mb limit per request and currently if the file is greater than 10mb, i receive a missing cors warning that blocks my client from parsing the 413 (which i have a logic for handling in the FE) console network error
I have enabled everything in my serverless yml for access-control-allow-origin: '*' and make sure it is there on my API Gateway responses. correctly configured aws gateway
Is it just impossible to append a CORS header to failed preflights from Gateway? what am i missing? I know i can use presigned S3 URL to solve the architecture work flow but right now i just want a quick fix for being able to parse the 413. Running a NEST js BE with serverlessExpress lambda handler
I tried to inject response headers via serverless, via manual aws toggle, via try-catch in my backend. nothing seems to give the CORS header for a failed prefight
